# How can a team win while rain stopped play permanently in 2nd innings?

Tags: cricket, interruption

The Team bat first scored 144/3 after 20 overs in T20 format match.. second Team scored 34/2 in 8.4overs . then rain stopped the play. who will won the match? explain please.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what method of resolution the league or competition has designated for this case.  If they use net run rate, for example, then team 1 has 7.2/over and team 2 has 3.9/over, so team 1 wins.  If they use Duckworth-Lewis, then the par score for team 2 would be 56, so team 1 wins.  (There are several online resources to calculate D/L; results may vary.)  There are other methods as well.

Comment: All tournaments organised under ICC's standards *have to* use the D/L method.